# Stop Evernote from using Location based services?

Tags: geolocation, evernote

Here is a screenshot from Evernote app:

[image]

How do I stop Evernote from using this service? I have looked around the settings but did not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.**First Turn -On your GPS**
2.**Go to Evernote Settings**
3.Under **General Settings** you can find **"Other Options"**
4.Uncheck **"Use GPS Satellites"** option. Also Uncheck **"Use wireless networks"**

If you didn't turn on your GPS, **"Use GPS satellites"** option get greyed out.
Now your note will not store your location.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use your GPS at all, just turn it off. Locations services will not be enabled and the "Places" Evernote service will not be used.